# TextInput unwanted Underline

Tags: react-native, textinput, underline

I'm working on a project which has some text fields(textInput). I'm encountering an issue with the textInput fields here. While I type in the textInput field the text is having an underline which is getting even more darker when I hit space and I want to remove that underline from it.

Here is a screenshot:
[image]

This is my code:

```
<TextInput
  style={Style.InputStyle}
  multiline={true}
  placeholderTextColor={'#DC1938'}
  placeholder={'Name'}
  spellCheck={false}
  underlineColorAndroid='rgba(255,0,0,0.3)'
  inlineImageLeft='userred'
  inlineImagePadding={25}
  padding={15}
/>
```

Comment: You will need to provide some of your codes. What is the style in your textinput?

Comment: Harikrishnan , check my answer below it will solve your problem.

Comment: see i  need a baseline of red color but dont want an underline

Comment: Before implementing any component read its [docs](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/) carefully.

Comment: @HarikrishnanS Are you able to remove underline from TextInput?

Comment: @SagarChavada yeah! see my answer below

Comment: @HarikrishnanS see this:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48638667/underlinecolorandroid-not-working-in-android/48638948?noredirect=1#comment84274426_48638948

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hello guys i have found the answer it was the autoCorrect prop. i disabled it and yeah it worked!

Answer (score 5):

Try Following props.

```
spellCheck={false}
autoCorrect={false}
```

Please refer the following link :

[disable spellcheck in react-native TextInput](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/textinput.html#spellcheck)

Comment: see disable spellcheck is not working with it.i still get the same issue

Comment: not working :( :(

Answer (score 1):

Use ***underlineColorAndroid*** props

```
<TextInput underlineColorAndroid='transparent'
       placeholder="type here ..">
   This is some text you want to render
</TextInput>
```

An explanation why this happens can be found [here](https://xinyustudio.wordpress.com/2013/08/26/android-edittext-control-using-old-rectangle-style/).

[image]
[image]