# underlineColorAndroid not working in android

Tags: android, react-native, textinput

```
react-native-cli: 2.0.1
react-native: 0.52.2
```

In my ios device form looks good but in android device its showing bottom border on TextInput,

```
 class Input extends Component {

        render(){
            return(
                <View style={styles.container}>
                    <Text style={styles.lableStyle}>{this.props.label}</Text>
                    <TextInput
                         secureTextEntry={this.props.secureTextEntry}
                         placeholder={this.props.placeHolder}
                         autoCorrect={false}
                         value={this.props.value}
                         onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}
                         underlineColorAndroid={this.props.borderColor} // not working
                         style={styles.textInputStyle} />
                </View>
            );

        }
    }
```

passing props from LoginForm:

```
render(){
        return(
            <Card>
                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                        borderColor="transparent" //props for border
                        label="Email"
                        placeHolder="abc@example.com"
                        onChangeText={this.onEmailChanged.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.email}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                <CardSection>
                    <Input 
                        borderColor="transparent" // props for border
                        secureTextEntry
                        label="Password"
                        placeHolder="password"
                        onChangeText={this.onPasswordChanged.bind(this)}
                        value={this.props.password}
                    />
                </CardSection>

                {this.errorRender()}

                <CardSection>
                    {this.spinerRender()}
                </CardSection>
            </Card>
        );
    }
```

ScreenShot of mac

[image]

ScreenShot of android

[image]

Comment: Try to put the string 'Transparent' between { }.

Comment: Have you tried pass 'rgba(0,0,0,0)' instead?

Comment: yes i tried that too..  not working.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Finally solved it. 
underlineColorAndroid attribute not work for me. so i add style in android res.

open this path: 
android/app/src/main/res/values/styles.xml

And add this lines in style:

```
<item name="colorAccent">#FFFFFF</item>
<item name="colorControlNormal">#FFFFFF</item>
```

it will work for android

Answer (score 0):

change your  to this in your loginForm

```
           <Input 
                    borderColor='transparent'// props for border
                    secureTextEntry
                    label="Password"
                    placeHolder="password"
                    onChangeText={this.onPasswordChanged.bind(this)}
                    value={this.props.password}
                />
```

Comment: in my case underlineColorAndroid attribute not working.. but its solved now, see my answer

Comment: ok just try the above answer as well because you were passing the border color prop in double quotes it should be in single quotes\

Comment: tried.. its not work either, maybe a bug with new version

Answer (score 0):

> TextInput has by default a border at the bottom of its view. This border has its padding set by the background image provided by the system, and it cannot be changed. Solutions to avoid this is to either not set height explicitly, case in which the system will take care of displaying the border in the correct position, or to not display the border by setting underlineColorAndroid to transparent.

underlineColorAndroid="transparent"
and
padding:0